# MVC hybrid still calls default.aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an app that has both integrated MVC5 and Webforms. I'm in the process of converting it from WebForms to MVC, one step at a time. After I added my controllers, vies, etc., I added my MVC routing as in the following. But for some reason, when I launch the app (F5), the Default.aspx page still opens instead of my Home/Index. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Default.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

EDIT: I just figured it out but don't understand why. It seems that when I go to  the project's properties and set the Server to "Use Visual Studio Development Server", then it displays my Default.aspx page on startup. But when I change it to "Use Local IIS Web Server", then the MVC Url routing kicks in and opens my Home\Index page. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the above behavior only if i comment out Route registrations in the Application_Start (see commented lines in my Global.asax below). Otherwise it just works perfectly fine in a sample webforms and mvc5 hybrid project.

Here's my Global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);            
        }
```

Here's my RouteConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new {controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
```

Comment: I added more details to my question. I can reproduce the behavior by changing the server in the project's properties. But I don't understand why it does that.

Comment: What does your start action in the project properties -> Web section show?

Comment: The start action is set to Specific Page, but it is empty.

Comment: Can you change that to current page and see if that helps ?

Comment: Changed it to Current Page, but the Default.aspx page gets loaded when I select Visual Studio Development Server (VSDS). Does that mean that when you use MVC, you MUST select the Local IIS Server? It doesn't seem to want to use the MVC Routing mechanism when I select VSDS.